# The child process doesn't read PIPE

Tags: c, process, printf, pipe, fifo

```
#include    <sys/types.h>
#include    <sys/stat.h>
#include    <sys/mman.h>    
#include    <fcntl.h>
#include    <stdio.h>    
#include    <stdlib.h>  
#include    <string.h>  
#include    <unistd.h>
#include    <limits.h>  
#include    <pthread.h>
#include    <signal.h>
#include    <sys/select.h>
#include    <errno.h>

typedef struct rot* Rotacao; 
typedef struct rot{
   int idProcess;
   int rotacao;
   char url[50];
} roda;

struct stat statbuf;

void listen();
void * do_rotation();
void write_pixel();
void rotacao90();
void rotacao180();
void rotacao270();
void sig_handler();
struct pixel *get_pixel();
void trata();

char *src, buf[50];
int size, fileids90[2], fileids180[2], fileids270[2], idp;


int main(){
    int id[N], i = 0;

    int p, idPai = getpid();

    for(p = 0; p<3; p++){
        if(getpid() == idPai){
            if(fork() == 0){
                if(p == 0) rotacao90();
                else if(p == 1) rotacao180();
                else if(p == 2) rotacao270();
            }
        }
    }

    if(pipe(fileids90) != 0) printf("Não criou pipe 90!");
    if(pipe(fileids180) != 0) printf("Não criou pipe 180!");
    if(pipe(fileids270) != 0) printf("Não criou pipe 270!");

    if(getpid() == idPai){
        while(1){
        listen();
    }
}


void rotacao90(){
    printf("1 Processo chegou! ID = %d ; IDPai = %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
    char str[20];
    while(1){
        read(fileids90[0], str, strlen(str)+1);
        printf("%s", str);

    }
}

void rotacao180(){
    printf("2 Processo chegou! ID = %d ; IDPai = %d\n", getpid(), getppid());   
}

void rotacao270(){
    printf("3 Processo chegou! ID = %d ; IDPai = %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
}

void listen(){
int pipe, rot, fdmax, n;
    char str[20];


    Rotacao new = (Rotacao) malloc(sizeof(roda));
    Rotacao final = (Rotacao) malloc(sizeof(roda));

    //OPEN PIPE WITH READ ONLY
    if ((pipe = open ("FIFO_PIPE", O_RDONLY))<0){
        perror("Could not open named pipe for reading.");
        exit(-1);
    }


    while(1){
        fd_set master;
        FD_ZERO(&master);

        FD_SET(pipe, &master);
        if(pipe > fdmax) fdmax = pipe;
        FD_SET(fileids90[0], &master);
        if(fileids90[0] > fdmax) fdmax = fileids90[0];
        FD_SET(fileids180[0], &master);
        if(fileids180[0] > fdmax) fdmax = fileids180[0];
        FD_SET(fileids270[0], &master);
        if(fileids270[0] > fdmax) fdmax = fileids270[0];

        n = select(fdmax+1, &master, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        if (n == -1) {
            perror("select");
        }

        if (FD_ISSET(pipe, &master)){


            //READ FROM PIPE
            if (read(pipe,new,sizeof(roda)) < 0 ){
                perror("Error reading pipe.");
                exit(-1);
            }

            final->idProcess = new->idProcess;
            final->rotacao = new->rotacao;
            strcpy(final->url, new->url);

            if(final->rotacao == 90){
                printf("\ndsadasdas1");
                strcpy(str, "ola");
                write(fileids90[1], str, strlen(str)+1);
            }
            else if(final->rotacao == 180){
                printf("\ndsadasdas2");
            }
            else{
                printf("\ndsadasdas3");
            }

            trata(final);



            //CLOSING PIPE
            if (close(pipe)<0){
                perror("Error closing FIFO.");
                exit(-1);
            }

            //OPEN PIPE WITH READ ONLY
            if ((pipe = open ("FIFO_PIPE", O_RDONLY))<0){
                perror("Could not open named pipe for reading.");
                exit(-1);
            }


        } 
        if (FD_ISSET(fileids90[0], &master) == 1) printf("\nPipe90 com conteudo!");
        if (FD_ISSET(fileids180[0], &master) == 1) printf("\nPipe180 com conteudo!");
        if (FD_ISSET(fileids270[0], &master) == 1) printf("\nPipe270 com conteudo!");

    }

    //CLOSING PIPE
    if (close(pipe)<0){
        perror("Error closing FIFO.");
        exit(-1);
    }
}
```

Hello people. I've a problem that I dont understand. I have a Client and a Server. This is the server code. I receive a struct from the client and I want to send that struct to the process child that operates in function rotacao90(). In meanwhile I'm doing some tests and I'm sending a message to the parent process through a pipe. The Select function is not operating in a proper way and I don't understand why. In other way I already try to send a message from parent process to the child, but he doesn't read it. I need to do a comunication from server to child and from the child to server.

Can someone explain me or help me? This is for a project of my university.

Thank you.

Comment: Try to simplify your code to see if you can get a simpler version to work to make sure you understand what you're doing - for example, just have two processes communicating with simple messages instead of 4 or 5.

Comment: Your major error is you need to create the pipes to communicate with the child *before* the `fork`.  Parents/children do not share memory but the children inherit the file descriptors.  Exit your children so they don't fall through to execute the parent code (or run forever as in the case of 90).  Have the parent `wait` on the children when the processing is done.

Answer (score 1):

You create the pipes after the child processes have already been spawned (with `pipe(fileids90)` and so on), so the child processes won't have the file descriptors that the parent does.

Comment: No, the fork will only create the 3 children.  That much is ok, if a little unorthodox.